# Method union of object global failed for multirange union

Tags: vba, excel

I have below code which gives method union object global failed error when it runs. The highlight is showing some issue in set multirange line, tried to amend certain things by still it is giving the same issue. All the ranges are in one worksheet named Input.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, R13, R14, R15, R16, R17, R18, R19, R20, MultiRange1 As Range
Set R1 = Range("I23:Q25" & LR)
Set R2 = Range("D57:O62" & LR)
Set R3 = Range("D65:P70" & LR)
Set R4 = Range("C83:M85" & LR)
Set R5 = Range("O89:Q93" & LR)
Set R6 = Range("D149:Q154" & LR)
Set R7 = Range("D157:Q162" & LR)
Set R8 = Range("D212:H215" & LR)
Set R9 = Range("O212:Q215" & LR)
Set R10 = Range("E219:H230" & LR)
Set R11 = Range("L219:L230" & LR)
Set R12 = Range("N219:N230" & LR)
Set R13 = Range("P219:P230" & LR)
Set R14 = Range("R219:R230" & LR)
Set R15 = Range("C233:Q272" & LR)
Set R17 = Range("E74:K79" & LR)
Set R18 = Range("I8, I11, I13, I15, I17, I39, I172" & LR)
Set R19 = Range("I45, I52, F96, N96, F100, I105, I125, L144, I170" & LR)
Set R20 = Range("I175, I176, I182, G274, C278, E287" & LR)
Set MultiRange1 = Union(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, R13, R14, R15, R16, R17, R18, R19, R20)
MultiRange1.Select
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **DIM** and assign a value to `LR`.

Must also individually **DIM** each of the R's as `Range`

Also `R16` is undefined.

**EDIT#1:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim LR As String

    LR = ""

    Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, R3 As Range, R4 As Range, R5 As Range, R6 As Range, R7 As Range, R8 As Range, R9 As Range, R10 As Range, R11 As Range, R12 As Range, R13 As Range, R14 As Range, R15 As Range, R16 As Range, R17 As Range, R18 As Range, R19 As Range, R20 As Range, MultiRange1 As Range

    Set R1 = Range("I23:Q25" & LR)
    Set R2 = Range("D57:O62" & LR)
    Set R3 = Range("D65:P70" & LR)
    Set R4 = Range("C83:M85" & LR)
    Set R5 = Range("O89:Q93" & LR)
    Set R6 = Range("D149:Q154" & LR)
    Set R7 = Range("D157:Q162" & LR)
    Set R8 = Range("D212:H215" & LR)
    Set R9 = Range("O212:Q215" & LR)
    Set R10 = Range("E219:H230" & LR)
    Set R11 = Range("L219:L230" & LR)
    Set R12 = Range("N219:N230" & LR)
    Set R13 = Range("P219:P230" & LR)
    Set R14 = Range("R219:R230" & LR)
    Set R15 = Range("C233:Q272" & LR)
    Set R17 = Range("E74:K79" & LR)
    Set R18 = Range("I8, I11, I13, I15, I17, I39, I172" & LR)
    Set R19 = Range("I45, I52, F96, N96, F100, I105, I125, L144, I170" & LR)
    Set R20 = Range("I175, I176, I182, G274, C278, E287" & LR)

    Set MultiRange1 = Union(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, R13, R14, R15, R17, R18, R19, R20)
    MultiRange1.Select
End Sub
```

1. fixed the DIMs
2. established `LR`
3. removed `R16`

Comment: Hey Gary, i already have another multirange union with same setup running perfection in another workbook.

Can you please amend the code and show

Comment: @ShakirZahid  See my **EDIT#1**